# Inheritance of class in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance, methods

Suppose I have a parent class `A` and a daughter class `B`. Now `A` has 10 methods in it and B requires only three of those methods. How can this be done?

Comment: Can't `B` just *ignore* the other seven methods? Or could you refactor the shared methods into a superclass that both `A` and `B` share, making them siblings? If you want to override inherited methods in a class, just implement them within that class definition.

Comment: The [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) requires that a subtype B of A has at least the interface of A. If you don’t want that, then you probably don’t want B to be a subtype of A.

Comment: Make a parent class that has the 3 methods in it. Inherit the class A and class B from the parent. class A will keep its 7 methods and class B wont know anything about them. Similar to @jonrsharpe suggestion (I +1'd it) , but I advocate this approach to just "ignoring" the other seven methods, since if you are not the only developer then someday someone might forget why they are "ignoring" them.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special to do.

Just inherit class `A`:

```
class B(A):
    super(B, self).__init__():
```

Use/override the methods you need and ignore the rest.